# How to pass parameter to event from React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this two files, WordList.js:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import WordListItem from "./WordListItem";

function WordList(props) {
    var cards = props.cards;
    var cardsElements = null;

    var [ id, setId ] = useState('');

    function contextMenuClickHandler(id) {
        setId(id);
        console.log(id);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('click', function() {console.log(this)}.bind(id));
    }, []);

    if (cards != null) {
        cardsElements = cards.map( card =>
            <WordListItem
                value={card.original_word}
                key={ card.id }
                id={ card.id }
                visible={ card.id === id }
                contextMenuClickHandler={ contextMenuClickHandler }
            />
        );
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={ contextMenuClickHandler }>kek</button>
            { cardsElements }
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default WordList
```

And WordListItem.js:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './WordListItem.css';
import more from './more.svg';
import ContextMenu from './ContextMenu'

function WordListItem(props) {
    function contextMenuClickHandler(event) {
        props.contextMenuClickHandler(props.id);
    }

    return (
        <p className="word-list-item">
            { props.value }
            { props.visible ? <ContextMenu/> : null }
            <img src={ more } className="more-button" onClick={ contextMenuClickHandler } />
        </p>
    );
}

export default WordListItem;
```

First component - WordList is a list of WordListItem, and every WordListItem have ContextMenu component that displays when user clicks on img element. WordList stores id of WordListItem that must displays ContextMenu in concrete moment to have displayed only one ContextMenu in any time. To close this ContextMenu user must click to one of ContextMenu buttons. But i want that if user click in another space of document (any place) close ContextMenu too. In useEffect on WordList i add listener (with [] because document must have only one handler). I can pass parameter with id to documentClickHandler but parameter remains the same value after i update id. In answers people say me to write useEffect to update id. But how can i call useEffect?

**Added.**

i made this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('click', function() {console.log(this())}.bind(test));
    }, []);

    function test() {
        return Math.random();
    }
```

it works, handler have new value ever click, but if i make this:

```
    function test() {
        return id;
    }
```

where id i get from his:

```
    var [ id, setId ] = useState('');
```

And with state id, it doesn't work. I must use useEffect but how must i do this?

Comment: Don't forget to remove the previous listener if you run `useEffect` multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the dependency list of the useEffect hook as empty array, then the function `someFunction` will be called only on first render.

let the useEffect watch `id` and call the function whenever the `id` changes as following

```
useEffect(someFunction, [id])
```

And also call `setId` function whenever you want to change `id`

Answer (score 0):

add the id as dependency of the useEffect, like this the click event listener will be updated on id change :

```
useEffect(someFunction, [id]);
```